# THREE.js - CameraContros and camera.up vector

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using CameraControls (camera-controls) package to manage Camera on Three.js

When space is Y-axis up (camera.up.set(0,1,0)) it works just right, but when Z axis is set up (camera.up.set(0,0,1)) it stops working as expected.

Any clue how could I make CameraControls package work z-axis up?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change up vectors (scene objects/camera/orbit controls/THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp) - it brought more problems than benefits, IMHO.
I also tried to use rotation (recommended by many people here, at 'discourse' and 'clara.io') - but it didn't work.

Finally, I ended up with just modifying raw coordinates. You can do it on the client-side or on the server side.
In my scenario (I think this is your case too) the solution is to convert real-world coordinates into threejs-scene space coordinates and vice-versa like this:

```
threeX: -1 * worldX,
threeY: worldZ,
threeZ: worldY
```

Comment: Thanks SalientBrain. I tried to do that on the camera-controls lib buy I am sure I am doing something wrong. Problem is that the library works with SphericalCoordinates from Three.js, which does not take into accout the up vector of the Camera. I am making a proper SphericalCoordinates Class that takes camera into account, and that should solve it (in a cleaner way I hope)